# how comes I am getting unidentified messages and calls on Whatsapp?

Tags: contacts

I've started receiving messages and calls from an unidentified call with a number in Middle East +973 ....
how is this possible?.  I thought only my contacts could message me. Has my phone contacts file been hacked or that of one of my contacts?

Answer (score 3):

Everyone can message and call you on Whatsapp. It's like a usual sms and phone call. You can block this number by going to chat -> Menu -> More -> Block.